# How to change the parent of a commit in git and keep my branches?

Tags: git

I have a commit history and branches like this:

```
* 093ea3c (origin/development, development) Some development stuff
| * 697011a (HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/issue-1234, issue-1234) Add eee
| * 38cb60d Add dddd
| * ffdf58b Add ddd
| * 5809ecb Add dd
|/  
* 83eff5e Implement feature 2
* 59caf22 Implement feature 1
* 0f0aa34 Initial commit
```

Let's say I need to do some changes in commits `0f0aa34 Initial commit` and `83eff5e Implement feature 2`. I do it with `git checkout 83eff5e` and `git rebase -i --root`. This creates a commit history like this:

```
* 8506503 (HEAD) Implement feature 2
* b6d069a Implement feature 1
* 5e0b8a2 Initial commit
* 093ea3c (origin/development, development) Some development stuff
| * 697011a (origin/main, origin/issue-1234, main, issue-1234) Add eee
| * 38cb60d Add dddd
| * ffdf58b Add ddd
| * 5809ecb Add dd
|/  
* 83eff5e Implement feature 2
* 59caf22 Implement feature 1
* 0f0aa34 Initial commit
```

Now what I want to do is, I want my older work (branches) to have newly created commits as parents. In simple words, I just want to replace

```
* 83eff5e Implement feature 2
* 59caf22 Implement feature 1
* 0f0aa34 Initial commit
```

with

```
* 8506503 (HEAD) Implement feature 2
* b6d069a Implement feature 1
* 5e0b8a2 Initial commit
```

and keep my branchings. How can I do that? I know changing parents will change the SHAs of all commits. I couldn't manage to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to rebase your branch onto the new history:

```bash
# reset main branch to new HEAD 8506503 
git switch -C main 8506503 
# update main with commits from origin/main
git rebase --onto main 83eff5e origin/main

# same for development: reset it to new HEAD 8506503 
git switch -C development 8506503 
# update development with commits from origin/development
git rebase --onto development 83eff5e origin/development
```

Comment: Fantastic... I don't wrap around my head on everything but it worked. Notes: `git switch origin/main` gives an error. I used `git checkout`. I used `git switch -C` again at the end to move the branch from `8506503` to HEAD. Thanks again. I will dive deep into this.

Comment: @emremrah Actually, I suspect the git switch origin/... is not needed here. I will remove them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git filter-branch` for that. One way to do that is:

1. Commit your modification to `0f0aa34` on a temporary branch (`git checkout -b fix 0f0aa34`, then commit your modification).
2. Determine the full SHA-1 of that new commit ("FIXED_SHA1") and of `0f0aa34`.
3. Rewrite the history of all branches so that any commit that has `0f0aa34` as a parent now will use your fixed commit as a parent:

   `git filter-branch --parent-filter 'test $GIT_COMMIT = 0f0aa34... && echo "-p <FIXED_SHA1>" || cat' -- --all`

Answer (score 1):

I like VonC's proposal, but I think it is much simpler to pull it off with rebases:

```
git rebase 83eff5e main --onto 8506503
git rebase 83eff5e develop --onto 8506503
```

Then you can move the other branches around and force-push into the remote.

Comment: This actually worked like a charm too. Thanks a lot. Could you explain what it does differently?

Comment: I see that VonC has updated his recipe.... can't quite remember what he did before (and his current recipe looks very much like mine at the moment). What he is doing is forcing moving the _local_ branches to the tip of the commit you created after rewriting history and then, using the remote branches, he is placing the commits from each branch on the local branch. By letting rebase move the local branch when it's done, what he does in 2 steps, I do it in one step... but in essence, we are doing the same thing.